# Adding two distinct subclasses as their common superclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a class with a lot of subclasses in my code. Consider the following code:

```
class Dataset:
  def __init__(self, samples):
    self.data = samples

  def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, type(self)):
      return type(self)(self.data + other.data)
    return NotImplemented

  def __radd__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, type(self)):
      return type(self)(other.data + self.data)
    return NotImplemented

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.data)


class DatasetA(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, samples):
    super().__init__(samples)
    self.a = len(self.data)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.a}: {self.data}"


class DatasetB(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, samples):
    super().__init__(samples)
    self.b = sum(self.data)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.data} (sum: {self.b})"


d = Dataset([1, 2, 3])
a = DatasetA([4, 5])
b = DatasetB([6, 7])

print(d + d)
print(d + a)
print(a + d)
print(d + b)
print(b + d)
print(a + a)
print(b + b)
print(a + b)
print(b + a)
```

The idea is to define an `__add__` method in the superclass that won't require being overridden in each of the subclasses and will still add them correctly (for instance, two `DatasetB`s should add up to another `DatasetB`). This works correctly (the first 7 `print`s are fine), however there is one additional functionality I'd like to implement, represented in the last 2 `print`s.

I would like any two distinct subclasses to add up to the first common superclass. For example, `a + b` should result in a `Dataset` instance. Also if we add up instances of two subclasses of `DatasetB`, the result should be a `DatasetB` instance.

I've tried changing `return NotImplemented` to `return super().__add__(other)` (and similar for `__radd__`), but that resulted in an `AttributeError` on the 3rd `print` statement already.

Is there a way to implement this desired functionality without breaking the existing one (i.e. still have the first 7 prints execute properly), and without explicitly having to override `__add__` in each of the subclasses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change:

```
return type(self)(self.data + other.data)
```

to:

```
klass = next(c for c in type(self).mro() if c in type(other).mro())
return klass(self.data + other.data)
```

This will pick the most specific superclass the two have in common, leveraging the [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Comment: This works and I like this approach (although I additionally had to change the `isinstance` check to test for `Dataset` specifically, rather than for `type(self)`). For anyone interested, I left the code available at https://repl.it/@matedevita/Greatest-Common-Superclass-Addition

Comment: Without having tested it, I think you don't even need to override `__radd__` anymore.

Comment: That's a fun extra bonus. I had it in the original code, because a simple `__radd__ = __add__` would mess up the order, but with your code neither an actual override nor even such an assignment seems to be required.